# WSL does not have hpet at /dev/hpet

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, hpet

/dev/hpet appears to be absent in WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) - is there any way to enable it to allow for applications that read from /dev/hpet?

Comment: It appears to have been explicitly turned off in the [WSL kernel config](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/blob/db998769a92eb01159c74b1f461b502a49cc3aa2/Microsoft/config-wsl#L1869) by Microsoft.  You could try building your own kernel from the Microsoft sources and turning it on, but then there's the question of whether the VM itself has that functionality enabled, and I don't believe we have the ability to inspect or change the Hyper-V settings for WSL2.